# Correct way to add a newline into a php string so that it appears as so in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, string

I'm aware that PHP ignores enters/white spaces and the \n character doesn't work within a string, so how would one do this?

Comment: PHP does *not* ignore white space or `\n`. Do you mean *your browser when rendering HTML*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think \n doesn't work within a string? It does work.

You can do:

```
"asd\nasd"
```

Or:

```
"asd
asd"
```

Both will work just fine.

However:

```
'asd\nasd'
```

has the actual characters \n not a newline, so check which quotes you are using.

But:

```
'asd
asd'
```

works fine.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct.  As I commented below, I was confused because I echoed a variable to test it before inserting it, and made my assumption based on that.

Comment: @Sam yes, browsers collapse (not ignore) spaces and newlines into a single space. You can do `<PRE></PRE>` if you want to see raw form, you can check the source, or you can set the `Content-type: text/plain`